# how to analyze the output of valgrind

Tags: linux, valgrind

Working on a project using valgrind to check the code in process. I got errors from valgrind. But it was not specified the file name and line number. I have searched and guess there may be a symbol table that was missed. But I run it in gdb in which I can get the source code, look like the symbol table is there.

The following is output of valgrind.

```
45 ==10858==    by 0x808855E: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
46 ==10858==    Address 0x6fdb0cc is 24,244 bytes inside a block of size 24,640 free'd   
47 ==10858==    at 0x6CEB51D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)   4   
48 ==10858==    by 0x8087079: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
49 ==10858==    by 0x808BB1A: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
50 ==10858==    by 0x80AE3AD: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
51 ==10858==    by 0x813FADA: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
52 ==10858==    by 0x808B55A: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
53 ==10858==    by 0x8088593: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
54 ==10858==    by 0x808E175: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod/lt_l.exe)
55 ==10858==    by 0x9A8A5A: makecontext (in /lib/libc-2.5.so) 
56 ==10858==    by 0x808855E: ??? (in /repo3/mydir/project1/sw/build/automod
```

How to find where the problem is? That not specified file name and line no. was caused by makefile? (We use a complex makefile). or just by the output above, I still can locate the wrong code?

EDIT: can I use gdb to watch the stack address above to find the wrong code?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know which debug symbols that you are using? I would guess that you are using symbols that are compatible with GDB but not with Valgrind. If you try GDB debug symbols (-ggdb) it should work.

Comment: @Skaarjasaurus, thanks for the comments. I have put CFLAGS = -ggdb -ansi in Makefile, but it keeps the same.